# How do you create hover effects in leafletjs?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I am using leafletjs to create a virtual tour map. I have the code figured out for highlighting and displaying information for the buildings, but I can't figure out how to build the hover code. I need the tour to display the name of the building when hovering, and allow a click to bring up detail.

I'm using the code thusly:

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([79,-50], 5);
    var southWest = L.latLng(64, -179.82422),
        northEast = L.latLng(84.9, 39.47461),
        bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
        map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

    L.tileLayer('maps/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 6,
        minZoom: 3,
        attribution: 
            'Imagery &copy; 2015 College</a>',
        id: 'map-i875mjb7'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.polygon([
        [83.34425, -19.51172], 
        [83.2571, -15.86426], 
        [83.07408, -16.04004], 
        [82.78192, -17.31445], 
        [82.62569, -11.42578], 
        [82.36164, -11.29395], 
        [82.11236, -12.48047], 
        [82.37332, -22.71973], 
        [82.64822, -22.93945], 
        [83.34425, -19.51172]

    ],          {color: 'yellow',
        fillColor: '#fff',
        fillOpacity: 0.0
    }).addTo(map).bindPopup(popupcontent);
```

Obviously, I'm new to this, and could use whatever help can be offered! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet's L.Path (L.Polygon is extended from L.Path) does have mouse events. You can attach to them like this:

```
var polygon = new L.Polygon(...);

// Adding eventhandler, start listening
polygon.on('mouseover', function(){...});

// Removing eventhandler, stop listening
polygon.off('mouseover', function(){...});

// Add event handler, listens only once
polygon.once('mouseover', function(){...});
```

Events reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events

L.Path reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path

That said this looks to me like a perfect case for the [Leaflet.Label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) plugin. It opens on hover so you could use it for the description. Then just stick with `L.Popup` for the details.

Code:

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
  [83.34425, -19.51172], 
  [83.2571, -15.86426], 
  [83.07408, -16.04004], 
  [82.78192, -17.31445], 
  [82.62569, -11.42578], 
  [82.36164, -11.29395], 
  [82.11236, -12.48047], 
  [82.37332, -22.71973], 
  [82.64822, -22.93945], 
  [83.34425, -19.51172]
], {
  color: 'yellow',
  fillColor: '#fff',
  fillOpacity: 0.0
});

polygon.bindLabel('Lorem Ipsum');

polygon.bindPopup('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');

polygon.addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(polygon.getBounds());
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jzfD9L?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! This is a huge help, and your reply was incredibly fast.